# Adding Percent Column Based on Combination of 2 columns (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage, summary

I am having trouble with a query where I would appreciate your feedback.

I need to add a 'percentage' column (rounded to 2 decimal places) which calculates the % of total for each animaltype and size combination.

These are the selected columns from animals table:

- animaltype (sorted alphabetically)
- size (sorted in order: small, medium, large)
- total

Here is the code I have for summary query:

```
SELECT animaltype, size, SUM(total) AS Total FROM animals
WHERE sponsored_animalid IS NULL
GROUP BY animaltype, size
ORDER BY animaltype, size DESC;
```

This is how the sample output should look like: [image: Sample Output for Query]

- Percentage needs to be calculated for each animaltype and size combination.

Sample formula would be for example (animaltype: bird, size: small):

ROUND((total for Bird(Small) / SUM of total for all birds (small, medium, large) * 100) , 2) = 12.55% (refer to the sample output above)

I dont want to create a new table/view, just need a way to fix a percent column for the query output.

Thank you for your help.

Appreciate if someone can help me calculate percentage by animaltype and size combination.

Comment: Using this code helps calculate % of column total, but it doesnt help calculate % for each animal and size combination as shown in the sample output table

code:
    SELECT animaltype, size, SUM(total) AS total,
    ROUND(( SUM(total) * 100 / SUM( SUM(total)) OVER ()),2) AS percentage
    FROM animals
    WHERE sponsored_animalid IS NULL
    GROUP BY animaltype, size
    ORDER BY animaltype, size DESC;

Appreciate some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/) and review [ask]. In particular post table definition (ddl) and sample data, as text - **no images**, even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13) and the expected results from that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to compute this value. For example:

```
SELECT
  animaltype, 
  size, 
  SUM(total) AS Total,
  100.0 * SUM(total) / SUM(total) OVER(partition by animaltype) AS percent
FROM animals
WHERE sponsored_animalid IS NULL
GROUP BY animaltype, size
ORDER BY animaltype, size DESC;
```

Comment: Hey, I get this error on the code above: 
(psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "animals.total" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 5:       100.0 * SUM(total) / SUM(total) OVER(partition by animals)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you this query :

```
SELECT
  t1.animaltype,
  t1.size,
  SUM(t1.total) AS total,
  round(SUM(t1.total / t2.total) * 100, 2) percent
FROM
  animals t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        animaltype,
        SUM(total) total
    FROM
        animals
    GROUP BY
        animaltype
   ) t2 ON t1.animaltype = t2.animaltype
WHERE
   t1.sponsored_animalid IS NULL
GROUP BY
  t1.animaltype,
  t1.size
ORDER BY
  t1.animaltype,
  t1.size DESC;
```

Comment: Hello, with the code above- percent column appears will zero values